# Options below the "fold" of a select widget disappear

Tags: html, css

I have a form that spans over two columns. The first column has a `<select multiple>` (for which a `height` is specified), with a dozen `<option>`s, the first few are visible, the others only if you scroll down.

```css
.rest{
  columns: 2;
}

select{
  height: 10em
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul>
    <div class="rest">
      <li>
        <select multiple>
          <option>Value 1</option>
          <option>Value 2</option>
          <option>Value 3</option>
          <option>Value 4</option>
          <option>Value 5</option>
          <option>Value 6</option>
          <option>Value 7</option>
          <option>Value 8</option>
          <option>Value 9</option>
          <option>Value 10</option>
          <option>Value 11</option>
          <option>Value 12</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <select multiple>
          <option>Value 1</option>
          <option>Value 2</option>
          <option>Value 3</option>
          <option>Value 4</option>
          <option>Value 5</option>
          <option>Value 6</option>
          <option>Value 7</option>
          <option>Value 8</option>
          <option>Value 9</option>
          <option>Value 10</option>
          <option>Value 11</option>
          <option>Value 12</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</form>
```

So far so good.

Now when I select one of the visible options and then scroll down to select some more, the options below the fold have disappeared. I can scroll through the entire list *before* I select an option, but once I select one, the next one or two options remain visible but the later ones disappear.

This does not happen if I remove the two-column layout. This also does not happen if I remove the height specification (at least in my Brave browser – in the snippet here it still happens). This also does not happen in Safari.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Maybe it's browser / os specific issue. Can you switch?

Comment: It works fine on Safari and Firefox for Mac, but buggy as described above on Brave and Chrome. Can't really ignore Chrome issues though :( Haven't tried Windows browsers yet.

Comment: It still sounds odd. Is it has many options? It's a native `select` element, it should work the best..